# Why does my formula for date go away when form is submitted?

Tags: date, google-sheets, timestamp, google-forms, array-formulas

I want my **Google sheet** that is populated from a **Google form** to have a column that is just a date (8/5/2019) so that it can be easily merged into a google doc through automation of Autocart.

I inserted a column next to the time stamp and populated it with the formula

```
=TO_DATE(A5) 
=TO_DATE(A6)
=TO_DATE(A7)
```

and populated the whole column with this formula.

Whenever I test my form to see if it works the data is imported in but the formula in column B is taken away. Why does it take away my formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is expected behavior. you should use instead an array formula one row above eg if your first date starts in A5 paste this in 4th row:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({""; IF(LEN(A5:A), TO_DATE(A5:A), )})
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date"; IF(LEN(A2:A), TEXT(TO_DATE(A2:A), "m/d/yyyy"), )})
```

Comment: THANK YOU @player0 -  Works great.